# Is there a function that is to std::search what std::count is to std::find?

Tags: c++, stl

If the title sounds weird here is another explanation:

If I have a range *a*, and I want to count how many times another range *b* appeared in range *a*, is there a `std::` function to do it?

If no, is there a simple way to do it (ofc I can manually loop using `std::search` - I'm talking about something more elegant)?

Comment: I guess there is no such standard function because it's not clear whether it should count overlapped matches

Comment: @anatolyg true, actually motivation for this was me helping some young aspiring programmer to do count all words in a sequence... and we discussed is result for ("aaab", "aa") 2 or 1. :D

Comment: @anatolyg https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7784 ...

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll need to build your own. Here's what comes to my mind as an implementation.

```
template <typename Iterator1, typename Iterator2>
size_t subsequence_count(Iterator1 haystack_begin, Iterator1 haystack_end, Iterator2 needle_begin, Iterator2 needle_end) {
    size_t count = 0;
    while (true) {
        haystack_begin = std::search(haystack_begin, haystack_end, needle_begin, needle_end);
        if (haystack_begin == haystack_end)
            return count;
        count++;
        haystack_begin++;
    }
}

template <typename Iterator1, typename Iterator2, typename BinaryPredicate>
size_t subsequence_count(Iterator1 haystack_begin, Iterator1 haystack_end, Iterator2 needle_begin, Iterator2 needle_end, BinaryPredicate predicate) {
    size_t count = 0;
    while (true) {
        haystack_begin = std::search(haystack_begin, haystack_end, needle_begin, needle_end, predicate);
        if (haystack_begin == haystack_end)
            return count;
        count++;
        haystack_begin++;
    }
}
```

Some code using this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> haystack = {1, 19, 7, 23, 2, 19, 19, 19, 19};
    std::vector<int> needle   = {19, 19};

    assert(subsequence_count(begin(haystack), end(haystack), begin(needle), end(needle) == 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [std::count_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/) on range A with a lambda that uses std::find on range B.

EDIT: Replaced std::search with std::find.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this more efficiently than `O(nm)`, for `m` characters in the pattern, `n` in the string to be searched, you can consider a **suffix tree**. Essentially what this means is that you build a specialized tree structure that simultaneously describes all possible suffixes of a string. So if your string is "ratatat", your suffix string will simultaneously represent "ratatat", "atatat", "tatat", "atat", "tat", "at", and "t". So you can find (and count) all occurrences of a particular string very quickly once you've built the tree. Of course building it takes some programming effort, and some memory!

There is a very nice description [here](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/suffix-trees.shtml) (this refers to Skiena's book [The Algorithm Design Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849967202), which is where I read about them).

PS I started off searching for suffix tree C++ implementations. There are several useful stackoverflow questions on this, but nothing in std so far as I can tell.

*Edit to add alternative algorithm*

On second thoughts, I think that [**Boyer-Moore**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) string matching is probably a better solution, not least because there is a [`boost` implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/Searching.html#the_boost_algorithm_library.Searching.BoyerMoore) readily available -- and all you've said you want to do is find a particular search string (suffix trees are good if you want to count the occurrences of different search strings). Essentially what the b-m algorithm does is take advantage of structure in the search string to jump ahead when there is a mismatch, using a precomputed table for the search string (c.f. suffix trees which pre-process the string to be searched). So you ought to be able to manually loop with the boyer-moore boost search (rather than with the std search) and get a significant efficiency gain.

Comment: it is not n^2... for every elem of range you only read one elem of the other range.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Do you mean that it's really `O(nm)` where there are m characters in the pattern? Assuming so, I'm amending my answer.

Comment: I would guess so, for example think of aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa and aaaaab, also : Complexity

At most S*N comparisons where S = std::distance(s_first, s_last) and N = std::distance(first, last).

Comment: I put `O(n^2)` thinking I suppose that the pattern was in general some fraction of the string to be searched, but that is rather lazy and `O(nm)` is better.

Comment: boter moore wont work on custom data... " The algorithm allocates two internal tables. The first one is proportional to the length of the pattern; the second one has one entry for each member of the "alphabet" in the pattern. For (8-bit) character types, this table contains 256 entries. " so for int table has 4Gentries  :D

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt use boost :)

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/finder.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using boost::algorithm::find_all;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<double>  haystack{11.0,22.0,33.0,22.0,33.0,44.0,22.0,33.0,22.0};
    std::vector<double> needle{22.0,33.0};

    std::vector<boost::iterator_range<std::vector<double>::iterator>> out;
    boost::algorithm::find_all(out, haystack, needle);

    cout << "matches=" << out.size() << endl;
    cout << endl;

}
```

based on code that was posted as example of bug in find_all - link in comment to question.